# `Rake::Task['db:seed'].invoke` doesn't work - "Don't know how to build task 'db:seed'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake-task

I have a problem with testing my rake task. The task looks like this:

```
namespace :db do
  desc 'Load the seed data from db/seeds.rb'
  task :seed => :environment do
    puts 'seed'
  end
end
```

And my test like this:

```
require 'rake'
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Rake::Task do
  describe "db:seed" do
    it "runs a task" do
      Rake::Task['db:seed'].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

Everything looks ok, but I'm still getting that error:

> ```
>  Failure/Error: Rake::Task['db:seed'].invoke
>    RuntimeError:
>      Don't know how to build task 'db:seed' (See the list of available 
>      tasks with `rake --tasks`)
> ```

What's the most strange, the same task works when calling via console:

```
> rake db:seed
seed
```

Some ideas?

Answer (score 8):

To be able to invoke a task via

```rb
Rake::Task['...'].invoke
```

you should first load tasks via

```rb
Rails.application.load_tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a bypass:

```
RSpec.describe Rake::Task do
  describe "db:seed" do
    it "runs a task" do
      system('rake db:seed')
    end
  end
end
```